# cannot install MikTex 2.9 on Windows 10 Pro N (64 bit)

Tags: miktex

I had to uninstall MikTex, because it stopped working properly. Then I failed to install MikTex 2.9 on Windows 10 Pro N (64 bit). The message was:
This app can't run on your PC.
To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try to install as administrator?

Comment: I'm the only user of this desktop. Before I uninstalled MiKTeX, I was installing it absolutely in the same way. In my original post, I wrongly indicated OS. It's a 32-bit OS, x64-based processor.

Comment: Mmm… Did you download the 32-bit installer?

Comment: Yes. The installation failed when I was using installers from

Comment: The installation failed when I was using installers from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/setup/windows-x64, and also basic-miktex-2.9.6850-x64.exe from https://miktex.org/download

Comment: you should provide correct data in your question and provide more information about your rights on this PC and if you are behind firewall ... the best is to ask administrator for this PC that (s)he install MikTeX

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comment below the answer

Answer (score 1):

Even if hardware can run 64 bits a message such as "This app can't run on your PC" when combined with a secondary message about version such as [image] usually indicates trying to load a 64bit app whilst the OS is 32bit. **IF the Operating system is 32 bit** you need to download MiKTeX from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/setup/windows-x86

(Personally I prefer the portable version)

Comment: hm, i have installed MiKTeX 2.9.6880 64-bit, so it exist and it work fine.  as installer i use `basic-miktex-2.9.6753-x64.exe`. installation went smoothly.

Comment: @Zarko oleg said "I wrongly indicated OS. It's a **32-bit OS**, x64-based processor"

Comment: in question he claims that have 64-bit windows 10 pro :-(

Comment: I too have been caught out frequently by not analysing the OP comments more slowly

Comment: It perfectly works now with https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/setup/windows-x86